# Fully Understanding hreflang

Tags: html, internationalization, seo

I have a website which currently displays all prices in US dollars. I'd like to change it to pounds if you are from the UK and euros if you are from France or Germany. The text on the page will always be displayed in English.

I've explored the various options and most say that Google prefers you to offer different urls for each variation rather that simply render different content based on the users location/ip address.

Therefore say I'm on my shop home page I would offer the following urls (which display the appropriate currency):

- www.example.com/shop - default which is US dollars
- www.example.com/uk/shop - UK
- www.example.com/fr/shop - France
- www.example.com/de/shop - Germany

Obviously I don't want Google to penalise me for duplicate content. I have been researching hreflang to get by this but haven't quite fully grasped it as a lot of the examples are over simplified.

Say for example I am on www.example.com/shop. Would I simply render the following within the head?:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="http://www.example.com/uk/shop" hreflang="en-gb" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://www.example.com/fr/shop" hreflang="fr-fr" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://www.example.com/de/shop" hreflang="de-de" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://www.example.com/shop" hreflang="x-default" />
```

Now if I was on www.example.com/fr/shop would I need to render the same as above?

**Additional Questions:**

Should I provide a variant for en-us even though it would be the same as the default?

Also if the user was on www.example.com/shop and I detected the user was from France would I simply redirect the user to www.example.com/fr/shop? My trouble with this is how could someone in France see prices in dollars? I'm assuming I could store a cookie to make sure this redirection only happens the first time.

My final question is does this make sense to do this even though the text will still be in English and the content will only vary by price/currency?

I know that's quite a few questions but I'd really appreciate the clarification. Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not programming but about SEO

Comment: I'm not sure how this is off-topic. It's a programming question which affects SEO. I have added the HTML 5 tag to make it a little clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Obviously I don't want Google to penalise me for duplicate content.

Google does not penalize websites for duplicate content.

> Say for example I am on www.example.com/shop. Would I simply render the following within the head?

Yes.

> Now if I was on www.example.com/fr/shop would I need to render the same as above?

Yes.

> Should I provide a variant for en-us even though it would be the same as the default?

No.

> Also if the user was on www.example.com/shop and I detected the user was from France would I simply redirect the user to www.example.com/fr/shop? My trouble with this is how could someone in France see prices in dollars?

You should. Add a conversion button on your page.

> My final question is does this make sense to do this even tough the text will still be in English and the content will only vary by price/currency?

Not really, you should have translated text too.

Comment: Thanks @JVerstry. In response to the final question. If I didn't do it this way then how else could I display the different currencies? I don't wish to translate all the pages as this would take too much work.

Comment: Let the user configure their preferred currency and set it in a cookie. Then extract the currency from the cookie when they fetch the page.

Comment: That's kind of defeating the purpose. I'd like the user to automatically see the prices in their currency as soon as they come from the search engine.

Comment: Then you want to use Geotargetting: www.w3schools.com/htmL/html5_geolocation.asp or something based on their IP address. You will need to access a free service to convert the latitude and longitude into a country.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure I like that approach. I'm going to leave this question open for abit longer to see if anyone else has an opinion on the final question. Thanks for your clarification with the remaining points.

Comment: Why don't you like it?

Comment: For now I've decided to ignore the French and German versions and stick to English. This way I can utilize the hreflang and not have to worry about translating any content. Thanks again.